# what's the meaning of 'default' flag in chrome Experiments config?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium

[image]

the value 'default' means 'Enabled' OR 'Disabled'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This mean that it will not override default value defined by chromium at compile time. 
For example in this case on the latest chromium sources [it is disabled by default](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/base/features.cc?sq=package:chromium&dr=C&g=0&l=21):

```
const base::Feature kEnableTLS13EarlyData{"EnableTLS13EarlyData",
                                          base::FEATURE_DISABLED_BY_DEFAULT};
```

All flags could be observed [here](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/about_flags.cc?q=enforce-tls13-downgrade&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=2328). Just click on `net::features::` values to see the default value.